# Force MySQL to use specific index on ORDER BY clause with LIMIT to satisfy join

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mysql-8.0, order-by, limits

MySQL 8.0.30

I have three tables defined:

- C
- CT
- T

CT is a linking table (many-to-many between C & T)

The query I'm trying to optimize is of the following kind:

```
SELECT C.*, T.*
FROM C JOIN CT ON C.id = CT.cid JOIN T ON CT.tid = T.id
WHERE T.col = 8
ORDER BY C.pop
LIMIT 20
```

There are secondary indices defined on `T.col` and on `C.pop`.

The optimal query plan is to satisfy the query with the following join-order:

```
C (*using C.pop_idx*)
    join CT (c.id == ct.cid)
    join T (ct.tid == t.id)
    filter (T.col == 8)
```

There is no doubt that this is the optimal query plan, because of the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses.

What MySQL chooses instead is:

```
CT (table-scan)
    join T (using T.primary)
    filter T.col == 8
    join C (using C.primary)
```

I've tried everything I can think of:

- using FORCE INDEX
- query optimizer hints

```
(/* JOIN_ORDER(C, CT, T) */), /* INDEX(C, C.pop_idx) */, etc, etc
```

But to no avail.

The frustrating thing is that I've seen query plans where MySQL is smart enough to do exactly what I want it to do, viz. use the index defined on the ORDER BY/LIMIT to "filter" the rows in the outermost table as the outermost loop of a nested loop IJ, but I simply can't induce it to do so in this case.

Any ideas?

#### For those interested (not necessary to answer question)

The calculations as to why said query plan would be optimal in pseudo-code:

```
for each row in C [using index C.pop_idx read 20 rows (or so) in order at a time]
     for each matching row in CT (CT.cid == C.id) (using CT primary)
          for each matching row in T (CT.tid == T.id) (using T primary)
              if T.col == 8:
                   emit C.*, T.*
    
              if total emitted rows == 20:
                  done
```

Even if the % of T rows with `T.col == 8` is small (say, 1%), on average only 20 * 100 C rows would need to be read (which is way less than all the rows in CT).

Answer (score 0):

`CT` should have *only* these two indexes:

```
PRIMARY KEY(cid, tid),
INDEX(tid, cid)
```

Add these if necessary

```
C: INDEX(pop)
T: INDEX(cpl)
```

The Optimizer may decide to filter on `T.cpl` first, then reach for `C`.  Or it may decide to avoid sorting by starting with C.pop.

Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS` (for table sizes), `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (for other indexes and datatypes), plus a plain `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

If you don't need all the columns, consider not using `.*`.